# What is the practical reason behind power-of-two sized textures?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, textures

On one hand, I can understand the Mip-mapping (to be able to half the size recursive).
Is there anything else?

---

I'm just investigating if I have no intention to resize my textured sprites runtime, then I should not be aware of this power-of-two consideration, or still should for some performance/whatever reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Used to be that GPUs *required* such texture sizes. Then they improved & you could use other sizes, but at a performance penalty. Nowadays those restrictions have been relaxed to the point where you can forget all about it.

Also see https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/why-are-textures-always-square-powers-of-two-what-if-they-arent

Comment: There are still tradeoffs to using NPOT textures with OpenGL ES on iOS hardware: you don't get mipmapping and you can only clamp, not wrap.